# Scheduling script execution in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Does Eclipse provide a way to schedule the execution of a Java script? (e.g., if I need to schedule a script at 6 am, every day...)

Thanks.

Comment: A Java script or a JavaScript?

Comment: a java ___ script (anyName.java) :)....thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with any built-in service. Nevertheless, Eclipse is written in Java, so there's no problem writing your own Java code for doing this. You can use the [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class to schedule your code execution.

You "script" should be enclosed in an Eclipse plug-in. Use the `Activator.start` to schedule your process when the plugin loads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still not sure of the eclipse plugin. Here is the structure of my program:

public class A extends SeleneseTestCase {
@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {...}

@Test
public void testCase () {...}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown () {...}

The @Test method needs to be scheduled to run periodically (say at 6 am everyday). How do I "fit" the timer, plugin? Thanks.

Comment: There are several questions here. Q1: How to write Java code that will run periodically? Q2: How to write an Eclipse plugin with an activator. I suggest you start by Googling these two subjects. If you're still lost, you can ask more specific questions.